# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" for nested classes accessing parent class fields

Tags: c#, oop

Lets say that I have the following C# code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        public string ReturnSomething()
        {
            return someString;
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that an inner class could access state from its parent class, but when I try, I get the following error:

```
[CS0120] An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Foo.someString'
```

Changing `someString` to static does resolve the error, but I don't want to mark fields as static for this instance. Are there anymore workarounds for this?

Comment: `someString` must be `static` to be accessible from there. Otherwise, add a constructor `public Bar(Foo foo)`, keep a reference to `foo` and access it using `foo.someString`.

Comment: The constructor tip seems like an easy enough solution to go with. Doable in other languages, just not C#. Thanks anyway @aybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# (unlike Java for example, see [Nested Classes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)) does not associate instance of inner class with some instance of the outer, the main difference compared to usual classes is that in C# nested class can access internal members of enclosing one (static or instance when instance is provided). So you need to provide an instance in some way:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        public string ReturnSomething()
        {
            return new Foo().someString;
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Foo
{
    private string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        public string ReturnSomethingFromFoo(Foo f) => f.someString;
    }
}
```

If you want the "associated" behavior you will need to manually provide corresponding ctor and store associated instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        private Foo _foo;

        public Bar(Foo f) => _foo = f;

        public string ReturnSomethingFromFoo(Foo f) => _foo.someString;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [C# Nested types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

Comment: Or putting it another way: nested classes are inherently `static`

Answer (score 2):

You want to address `someString` (which belongs to `Foo` instance) from `Bar` instance, so you should
mention from *which* `Foo` instance, e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    // someString belongs to one of Foo instance
    public string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        // Instance someString belongs to
        private readonly Foo _foo; 

        public Bar(Foo foo) {
          _foo = foo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));
        }

        public string ReturnSomething()
        {
            // It's valid now: we want someString from _foo   
            return _foo.someString;
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to make `someString` being `static`:

```
public class Foo
{
    // someString doesn't belong to particular instance but to the class
    public static string someString;

    public class Bar
    {
        public string ReturnSomething()
        {
            // We want someString from class, not from instance
            return Foo.someString;
        }
    }
}
```